# Why isolated scope "&" is not working with controllerAs in directive of angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

index.html

```
<div ng-app="phoneApp">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl as AppCtrl">
    <div phone dial="ctrl.callHome('called home!')"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.js :

```
var app = angular.module('phoneApp', []);

app.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope) {
  var ctrl = this;
  ctrl.callHome = function (message) {
    alert(message);
  };
});

app.directive("phone", function () {
  return {
    scope: {},
    bindToController : {
      dial: "&"
    },
    controller       : controller,
    controllerAs     : 'controllerVM',

    templateUrl : 'node.html'
  };

  function controller(){
    controllerVM.onClick = function(){
      controllerVM.dial();
    }
  }
});
```

node.html :

```
<button ng-click="controllerVM.onClick()">Button</button>
```

when i click on Button of phone directive, it should call the function callHome of AppCtrl, but it is not getting called.

When i removes controllerAs from every where and calls the directive dial function from template directly, it is working properly

So please help me what am i missing?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has 2 problems. In your HTML, you are using '`ctrl as AppCtrl`' which is wrong. You should use '`AppCtrl as ctrl`'. The second problem is within phone controller, you have not defined controllerVM. You should define it like '`var controllerVM = this;`' I have inserted a working snippet below.

```js
var app = angular.module('phoneApp', []);

app.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope) {
  var ctrl = this;
  ctrl.callHome = function (message) {
    alert(message);
  };
});

app.directive("phone", function () {
  return {
    scope: {},
    bindToController : {
      dial: "&?"
    },
    controller       : controller,
    controllerAs     : 'controllerVM',

    template : '<button ng-click="controllerVM.onClick()">Button</button>'
  };

  function controller(){
    var controllerVM = this;
    controllerVM.onClick = function(){
      controllerVM.dial();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="phoneApp">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl">
    <div phone dial="ctrl.callHome('called home!')"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Could you please answer one more query
The above code is working fine but when i calling the dial function inside a callback function. It is not working. In my phone directive, i am making an http request and when it is succeeded, i am calling the dial function inside the callback of http request to notify the AppCtrl controller.

Comment: I found the error. i was passing the data like controllerVM.dial(id) but it should be passed as controllerVM.dial({id : id});